# php form several select with same name only the one selected

Tags: php, forms, select

I have a form with several `<select>` that have the same name and an onChange="document.forms['form_mes_reservations'].submit();" on all of them. Therefore, when I select an option from one of them, the page reloads and there is some PHP treatment done.

This is an example :

```
<form method="post" id="form_process">
     <select name="processed" onChange="document.forms['form_process'].submit();">
         <option value="1_choose">Please choose...</option>
         <option value="1_yes">Yes</option>
         <option value="1_no"></option>
     </select>

     <select name="processed" onChange="document.forms['form_process'].submit();">
         <option value="2_choose">Please choose...</option>
         <option value="2_yes">Yes</option>
         <option value="2_no"></option>
     </select>

     <select name="processed" onChange="document.forms['form_process'].submit();">
        <option value="3_choose">Please choose...</option>
        <option value="3_yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="3_no"></option>
     </select>

     <select name="processed" onChange="document.forms['form_process'].submit();">
        <option value="4_choose">Please choose...</option>
        <option value="4_yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="4_no"></option>
     </select>
</form>
```

What I'd like to know is this : is there a way to know which select has triggered the onChange ? Let me explain : in the $_POST['processed'], I get ALL the selected options, so if I have only selected "3_yes", I'll get something like this :

- 1_choose
- 2_choose
- 3_yes
- 4_choose

Is it possible to only have "3_yes" as a result ? Potentially, this is going to be a very long list of selects and I don't want to check all of them for changes...

Comment: Is processed[] worked for you ?

Comment: Sounds like a job for AJAX to me

Comment: Is wrong approach to have more that one form element with same name, add `processed[]` and check received POST array.

Comment: @DeepKakkar / mitkosoft : it does the same thing, I've just tested it... I'd like to avoid having to check every line for changes. Isn't it possible to know which select has triggered the onChange event ?

Comment: make differ id for them and use jQuery each()

Comment: @DeepKakkar I've looked for it but I'll still have to iterate through the whole array, no ?

Comment: @DanZ. is not necessary to check every line, just check which select is selected going trough passed array - see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make all select elements as array and check which is selected:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="form_process" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="processed[]" onChange="document.forms['form_process'].submit();">
        <option value="1_choose">Please choose...</option>
        <option value="1_yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="1_no"></option>
    </select>

    <select name="processed[]" onChange="document.forms['form_process'].submit();">
        <option value="2_choose">Please choose...</option>
        <option value="2_yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="2_no"></option>
    </select>

    <select name="processed[]" onChange="document.forms['form_process'].submit();">
        <option value="3_choose">Please choose...</option>
        <option value="3_yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="3_no"></option>
    </select>

    <select name="processed[]" onChange="document.forms['form_process'].submit();">
        <option value="4_choose">Please choose...</option>
        <option value="4_yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="4_no"></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST['processed'] AS $key => $value){
        if(strpos($value, 'choose') !== false){
            unset($_POST[processed][$key]);
        }
    }
    print_r($_POST['processed']);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2_yes
)
```

Comment: So it's going to check every single element and unset those that didn't change, right ? Isn't it a problem (in terms of processing time) if there are 1,000 elements ?

Comment: well, if you want to POST single element, you must define different form for each of them, i.e. to submit different form. other option is to disable all other elements before posting .it is not possible to 'filter' which element to be posted within one and the same form without additional work, so PHP approach will be much more efficient rather than disabling elements on front-end level.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought. Thank you very much for your answer @mitkosoft !